# Is there a way to Command-N a new term ssh'd into another server?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, xterm, iterm2

I'm becoming fond of iTerm2, especially since my dumb mighty mouse doesn't do such a great job at 3-button emulation, or I'd stick with X, but I digress.  Some background:  In my X environment, I can single click with a mouse and I've got a new xterm securely logged into one of my VM's.  Yeah, I know, it's just an aliased `ssh whmcclos@osxvm1` away, but I'm a vi guy.  Enough said.  Is it possible to setup iTerm2 to have a profile that opens a terminal ssh'd to one of my VM's, similar to what I've done for years with various X window managers?

Comment: Perhaps even a way to export an environment variable based on iterm2 profile would do, because I could add the logic into one of my start-up files, like `.bashrc`, or similar approach.  Any advice for doing an `ssh` right from a `bash` startup file? Like do I need to `exec` it, or anything else funky like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.  All you need to do is create a new profile with your command set to `ssh user@host.example.com` rather than `bash`.

Comment: Thanks.  Right in front of my face, and I tabbed by it a dozen time.  :-)

Comment: No problem; it took me a while to notice that myself when I wanted to do the same thing.

Comment: Sometime, change the word, _shell_, to, _Command_, in the above answer; I accepted it anyway, but the precise spot to put `ssh parallels@192.168.0.72` is in the next field, the _Command:_ field.  Wouldn't want to confuse anyone. :-)  Thanks again.